# Identification possibility of sorting an array by deleting not more than one element

Tags: c++, algorithm

Program gets a number of int arrays with size [2; 2000]. The question is: can that arrays get sorted after deleting not more than one element.

Examples:

2 16 3 3 - after deleting '16' it would be non-increasing array.

4 16 3 15 - there is no way to make it sorted.

Simple way: deliting first incorrect element and checking the fact of sorting. It takes too much time if there is a great number of arrays or that arrays are big-sizes.
Except cases, there incorrect element is first or last, and there array size is less than 4, in what way cheking that possibility can be accelerated

Comment: *Can someone write algorithm*: This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2):

simply iterate through the array, and if you notice `N_x > N_x+1` remove N_x, and mark that you removed 1 number...

in case you found another `N_y > N_y+1` where `y!=x`, then it can't be sorted.

I'll leave the implementation for you, as it is your homework after-all.

Comment: But there is a number of different situations:

5 4 5 5 2 1 or 5 4 5 4 2 1 so what do we need to delete? Checking all the cases needs a lot of time.

I did not ask someone, before i tryed ewerything I can. I thought someone knows simplier algorithm.

Comment: yeah, repeating N_x is an issue, but you can get around it easily, by checking it when removing N_x... check that N_x-1 != N_x

Comment: That was not problem of my example, in (5 4 5 5 2 1) deleting 4 will make it non-incresing, at second example deleting 5 will make it non-incresing, there was no situation where N_x-1 == N_x is true.

In case of array is big-sized, deleting one element and verification whole array takes too much time, and it can be non-increasing and non-deceasing, checking all the variants takes double time

Comment: i c, stand corrected...

Comment: I could made a mistake while asking question. More correct question is: what is good way of checking this possibility if there are a lot of big-sized arrays.